# байт код картинки в тип данных image SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, ado.net

В поисках решения, на многих сайтах, в том числе и этот, предлагают решение в виде запроса с параметрами.

Пример c MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/inserting-an-image-from-a-file :

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(  
    connectionString))  
  {
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(  
    "INSERT INTO Employees (LastName, FirstName, " +  
    "Title, HireDate, ReportsTo, Photo) " +  
    "Values(@LastName, @FirstName, @Title, " +  
    "@HireDate, @ReportsTo, @Photo)", connection);
  
  command.Parameters.Add("@LastName",
     SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = lastName;  
  command.Parameters.Add("@FirstName",
      SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = firstName;  
  command.Parameters.Add("@Title",
      SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = title;  
  command.Parameters.Add("@HireDate",
       SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = hireDate;  
  command.Parameters.Add("@ReportsTo",
      SqlDbType.Int).Value = reportsTo;  
  
  command.Parameters.Add("@Photo",  
      SqlDbType.Image, photo.Length).Value = photo;  
  
  connection.Open();  
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();  
  }
```

Исходя из цели вопроса, хотелось бы узнать, какой необходимо создать запрос, чтобы не используя параметры для запроса, отправить байт код в тип данных image в SQL.
Пробовал отправить запрос без параметра и с параметром, и как вы поняли, запрос с параметром сработал и картинка выводится.

Результат с параметром:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000...
```

Результат без параметра:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D
```

Была загружена одна и та же картинка, но как вы можете заметить, картинка в обеих случаях имеет разное содержимое и разную длину. После недолгой проверки, было замечено возможная строчка, которая решает всю эту тему.

Строка:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@ImageData", SqlDbType.Image, 1000000);
```

Как я понял, здесь указывается тип image базы данных и количество символов(длина).

Задал вопрос GPT. Не знаю, кто, как к нему относится, но он выдал следующее сообщение:

> К сожалению, вы не можете отправить изображение в виде байт кода в тип
> данных image в SQL, не используя параметры команды.  Параметр
> позволяет указать тип данных для значения параметра, что очень важно,
> чтобы избежать ошибок при выполнении запроса в SQL Server.

Comment: А вопрос то в чем? Как отправить параметр запроса не используя параметр запроса? 1) зачем? 2) в чем прикол? Код, приведенный выше с параметрами, выглядит хорошо. Ну, за исключением того что `SqlCommand` реализует `IDisposable`. А вообще можно перестать мучаться с ADO.NET и поизучать Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

К великому сожалению, не получилось сделать красиво, и все-таки использовал параметр.
Распишу некоторые новые решения, которые заметил при использовании `ADO.NET` и также укажу некоторые моменты, которые дадут подсказку для решения, может поможет для тех, кто столкнулся с такой же проблемой.

Особенности `ADO.NET`:

`ADO.NET` довольно обширный инструмент по управлению базы данных. И довольно много вещей продумано. Первое, на что стоит обратить внимание, это написание запроса в базу данных.

Есть несколько методов написания:

1. Если вам нужен вывод данных с помощью `SELECT`, то прописывайте через `adapter`

Пример:

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                dataTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

Таким образом вы сможете получить таблицу данных в виде `DataTable`. Для вывода в `DataContext` просто укажите ваш `DataTable`.

Для вывода в разные элементы управления(`ListBox`, `DataGrid`, `ComboBox` и т.д.) необходимо конвертировать в `DataView` с помощью метода `DefaultView`.

Пример:

```
dataGrid.ItemSource = dataTable.DefaultView
```

2. Для добавление, изменение, удаление в базу данных, составляется запрос с помощью `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.

Примеры:

```
UPDATE table SET columnName = variable, ... WHERE ...
INSERT INTO table VALUES (variable, ...)
DELETE FROM table WHERE columnName = variable ...
```

Реализовать данные запросы можно следующим образом:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Перейдем к особенностям написания. Есть возможность заменить параметры и вписывать переменные в запрос. Для этого в начале запроса ставим символ `$`

Пример:

```
 string query = $"SELECT '{columnName}' FROM table";
```

Также можем соединить несколько запросов в один:

```
string query = $"SELECT '{columnName}' FROM table" +
               $"DELETE FROM table WHERE columnName = '{variable}'";
```

Теперь перейдем к данному вопросу. Решений я не нашел, но, возможно, кто-то найдет. Главная проблема это тип данных. Я пытался пропихнуть тип данных `byte[]` в `image`, но главная проблема, что так нельзя, поэтому приходиться использовать параметр, так как можно указать размер массива и тип данных, в данном случае тип данных, который нужен `SqlDbType.Image`.

Пример:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET columnName = @ImageData WHERE columnName = variable";
command.Parameters.Add("@ImageData", SqlDbType.Image, 1000000);
command.Parameters["@ImageData"].Value = image_bytes;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Если попробовать совместить метод написания запроса с использованием `$` и `SqlDbType.Image`, то получиться написать в одну строчку. Будет меньше кода и намного понятнее.

И вообще изучайте и используйте новые инструменты для управления базы данных, например EF.

Comment: Параметры это не только инструмент для передачи в запрос разных типов данных, это еще и защита от SQL-иньекций. Интерполяцию в запросах использовать строго не следует в первую очередь **из соображений безопасности**, это вредно, а уж потом всё остальное.

Comment: Я же сказал чем, внутренней защитой от SQL-иньекций. Почитайте про них что-нибудь. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892205/12888024

Comment: Давайте я объясню разницу между использованием параметров и составлением sql-запросов конкатенацией. В первом случае ваш начальник одобрительно хлопает вас по плечу и отправляет в кассу за чемоданом денег. Во втором случае реакция будет: "Вы уволены!"